# Foreach with different label

Tags: graphs, latex3, foreach, coordinates

Is there a simple way to have display my coordinate system?

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [-latex,thick] (0,0)--(12.5,0);
        \draw [-latex,thick] (0,0)--(0,10.5);
        \foreach \y in{2,4,...,10}
        \draw (0,\y) node [left] {\y};
        \draw (1,0) node [below] {5};
        \draw (2,0) node [below] {10};
        \draw (3,0) node [below] {15};
        \draw (4,0) node [below] {20};
        \draw (5,0) node [below] {25};
        \draw (6,0) node [below] {30};
        \draw (7,0) node [below] {35};
        \draw (8,0) node [below] {40};
        \draw (9,0) node [below] {45};
        \draw (10,0) node [below] {50};
        \draw (11,0) node [below] {55};
        \draw (12,0) node [below] {60};
        \draw (0,0) node [below left] {0};
        \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (12,10);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Like with for each [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below a solution that uses `\foreach`.

Moreover, I see that you have two different scales in your diagram. In this case, it is useful to use `xscale` (or `yscale` if needed), so that you can use the actual x values that you need instead of the absolute geometric x-values. `xscale` is set to a value that is the ratio between the maximum absolute geometric x-coordinate (12), and the maximum actual x-coordinate (60), so that `xscale = 12/60 = 0.2`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  xscale=0.2,>=latex,
  help lines/.style={black!50,ystep=1,xstep=5}]
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (60,10);
  \draw[<->] (0,10.5) |- (62.5,0);
  \foreach \x in {5,10,...,60} \node [below] at (\x,0) {\x};
  \foreach \y in {2,4,...,10} \node [left] at (0,\y) {\y};
  \node [below left] at (0,0) {0};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you want to do heavy plotting in this graph, consider using the `pgfplots` package instead of pure TikZ.

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose/usage of >=latex?

Comment: @AlessandroLin `>=latex` sets the arrow's head to have the shape called `latex`. In your code you used `-latex`, which has the same effect., however, iin your case you have to specify the arrow's head every time you draw an arrow. It is much more practical to redefine the arrow's head style altogether with `>=latex` as an option to the `tikzpicture` environment to have all arrow's heads of shape `latex`.